# Electric field and stationary currents

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Ohm's law says us that 
$$
\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}
$$
Where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the medium. It is also known that for stationary currents I can write
$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{1}{\sigma}\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} = 0
$$
So there aren't charges piling up. Now the question: I've understand that for these cases and when the medium is a perfect conductor I can say that $\vec{E} = 0$ because the huge value of $\sigma$, so what about a resistor? Is in this case $\vec{E}\neq0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\vec{E}$ is non zero inside the resistor, and that is why there is a change in potential across it

Answer (score 0):

After an initial turn-on transient static *surface* charges will accumulate at the terminals of a resistor. In fact, the static field induced by these opposing charges *is* the cause of the current through the resistor. For details, see, Muller: "A semiquantitative treatment of surface charges in DC circuits", Am. J. Phys. 80 (9), September 2012.